# Google Sheet - copy row if checkbox is active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

CONTEXT

In a google spreadsheet, copy entire row to another tab when checkbox is active
The below code works and was found online in [Code source](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/9604277/can-i-create-an-auto-copy-row-to-another-sheet?hl=en)

```
 function onEdit(event) {
  // source sheet named Source A
  // target sheet of move to named Development
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 21
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Source A" && r.getColumn() == 21 && 
r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Development A");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true});

}
}
```

PROBLEM

- I would like to have this code working in 2 tabs (sheets): Source A and Source B to 2 different destination sheets: Destination A and Destination B
- Limitation of one onEdit(event)

WHAT I'VE TRIED

- Adding "else if" to the code but it only worked for Source A:

  `else if if(s.getName() == "Source B" && r.getColumn() == 21 &&` etc
- Instead of using onEdit(event), named each function and then tried to use triggers (onEdit) but nothing worked

Can anyone give me a hand?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Source A','Source B'];
  if (~shts.indexOf(sh.getName()) && e.range.columnStart == 21 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.range.setValue("FALSE");//reset the checkbox
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Development");
    var tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(tgt, { contentsOnly: true });
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Source A','Source B'];
  const tgts = ['Dest A','Dest B'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == 21 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.range.setValue("FALSE");//reset the checkbox
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(tgts[idx]);
    var tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(tgt, { contentsOnly: true });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I edited the original post because with your answer I've noticed I forgot to mention that each source should be copied to a different destination (Development A, Development B) instead of both being copied to the "Development" sheet.